Gitlab CI/CD running jobs in docker compose
I want to run tests in docker compose using Gitlab CI/CD.
First I create and run containers in docker-build, but in run-tests the containers are no longer there. Can you tell me if there is any way to save the containers or how to do it differently?
.gitlab-ci.yml file
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

image:
  name: docker:26.1.3

services:
  - docker:26.1.3-dind

before_script:
  - docker version
  - docker compose version
  - docker compose ps

docker-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker compose down
    - docker compose up -d --build

run-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker compose exec app php vendor/bin/codecept run

I've tried linking jobs to each other, but nothing works

Jobs are in different stages so different machines, when docker-build ends run-tests does not have context on what happened.

The service containers, in this case docker:26.1.3-dind, are job specific. The docker engine is thus started at the beginning and terminated at the end of each job. Each docker:26.1.3-dind service container starts new instance of Docker daemon that does not share resources with earlier or following stages.
To pass images from build job to test job, you could, for example, use GitLab container registry as an intermediate storage for the images. For example:
image: docker:cli
services:
  - "docker:dind"
before_script:
  # Login to GitLab container registry in each job
  - echo "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" | docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # Create example Dockerfile
    - echo 'FROM alpine' > Dockerfile
    - echo "RUN echo 'Hello!' > /root/hello.txt" >> Dockerfile
    # Build the image
    - docker build . -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/hello:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    # Push the image to GitLab container registry
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/hello:$CI_PIPELINE_ID

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker images # No images listed
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/hello:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - docker images # The image built in build job listed

